# Flexbox not pushing content down after wrapping

Tags: html, css, flexbox, css-grid

Sorry if this question has been answered before, but I couldn't find a similar one. Having an issue with flexbox that is driving me nuts. I have two sections in a website, the top section contains a flex container row with two columns, that is wrapping on a 350px breakpoint that I have set on the left column via min-width. The right column contains a little grid with 4 elements.

```css
section#porque-montiperes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 550px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

section#porque-montiperes .row {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

section#porque-montiperes .row .left-column {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 350px;
  background-image: url(../img/lock.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

section#porque-montiperes .row .right-column {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  padding: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  gap: 10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#latest-works {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  background: #cc0;
  height: 800px;
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!--SECTION TOP -->
<section id="porque-montiperes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-column">
      <div class="porque-montiperes-heading">
        <h5>Porquê escolher a</h5>
        <h2>MontiPeres</h2>
        <button class="cta ">
                            Saber mais
                            <img src="img/icons/seta.svg" alt="">
                        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <div class="info-box">
        <img src="img/icons/escudo.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>
          <h5>Qualidade</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box">
        <img src="img/icons/sucesso.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>
          <h5>Experiência</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box">
        <img src="img/icons/cadeado.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>
          <h5>Segurança</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box">
        <img src="img/icons/acordo.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>
          <h5>Profissionalismo</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>

<!--SECTION BOTTOM -->
<section id="latest-works">
  <h1 style="text-align:center;margin-top: 100px;">bottom section</h1>
</section>
```

This is what I have before the wraping:
[image]

When the wrapping occurs, the bottom section is not being pushed down as supposed to, and I can't figure it out why. This is what is happening

[image]

Can someone help me with this one?

Comment: You have a height `height: 550px;` set on `section#porque-montiperes`. You need to either not set a height, or change your markup to allow that section to grow.

Comment: how silly of me..I have set height: auto on the section and set the height on the left column instead and it did the trick. Thank you for pointing me on the right direction @disinfor

Comment: I'm voting to close this, since it was essentially a "typo". Glad you got it figured out now!

Answer (score 0):

There's a few problems in the code you pasted that I cleaned up as well -- your CSS is nested -- is it LESS or SASS or something? I switched your $color variable to a gray so I could use it as well.

But the change that fixes the problem is in line 3 -- your height should be a "min-height" instead, to allow the content to take more than 550px if needed. As it is, the bottom section is covering up overflow, not content.

```css
section#porque-montiperes {
  position: relative;
  width: 100vw;
  min-height: 550px;
  margin-top: 150px;
}

.row
{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.left-column {
  flex: 1;
  height: 100%;
  min-width: 350px;
  background-image: url(../img/lock.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}
.right-column {
  flex: 1;
  display: grid;
  padding: 25px;
  grid-template-columns: 250px 250px;
  grid-template-rows: 50% 50%;
  gap:10px;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  max-height: 100%;
}

#latest-works {
    text-align:center;
    margin-top: 100px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    background: gray;
    height: 800px;
    margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<section id="porque-montiperes">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="left-column">
      <div class="porque-montiperes-heading">
        <h5>Porquê escolher a</h5>
        <h2>MontiPeres</h2>
        <button class="cta ">
          Saber mais
          <img src="img/icons/seta.svg" alt="">
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
      <div class="info-box"> 
        <img src="img/icons/escudo.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>                    
          <h5>Qualidade</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box"> 
        <img src="img/icons/sucesso.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>                    
          <h5>Experiência</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box"> 
        <img src="img/icons/cadeado.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>                    
          <h5>Segurança</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="info-box"> 
        <img src="img/icons/acordo.svg" alt="qualidade montiperes" width="50px" height="50px">
        <div>                    
          <h5>Profissionalismo</h5>
          <p>Quis anim ullamco do commodo deserunt eu culpa Lorem mollit. Deserunt incididunt enim magna consectetur enim deserunt nulla amet anim ullamco incididunt.</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>   
</section>

<!--SECTION BOTTOM -->
<section id="latest-works">
  <h1>bottom section</h1>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

You could add `display: inline-block;` to the first `section` element. Hope this helps!